# Как соединить файловые пути в один?

Tags: c++

```
#include "Application.h"
#include "STLParser.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
//#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int Application::execute(int argc, char* argv[])

{
    STLParser parser;
    
    
    std::string path;

    std::ofstream fouth(path);//Path to file
    
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        path = argv[1];
    }
    
   
    fs::path f(path);
    if (!fs::exists(f)) { //Check if file exists

        return 1;
    }
   
    //path = "C:\\Amc\\from - triangle - to - scene - 1 - 0 - q4 - 22\\Sphere(2).stl"


    std::string po;
    fs::path path1(path);

    std::cout << path1.filename() << '\n';


    
    std::cout<<path1.parent_path() << '\n';

    std::cout << path1.extension()<< '\n';

    std::cout << path1.stem() << '\n';
   

    //to string

    std::string output = "Sphere.stl";
    
    TriangleSoup triangleSoup =  parser.read(path);

    parser.write(triangleSoup, output);
    
    return 0;
    
  
}
```

Мне нужно соединить path1.parent_path() с path1.stem и path1.extension и получить новый путь к файлу а потом этот путь сконвертировать в to_string

Comment: Мне нужно cклеить path1.parent_path() с path1.stem и path1.extension

Comment: с этого у меня получиться путь и потом я этот путь сконвертирую в string

Answer (score 1):

У класса `std::filesystem::path` есть встроенные операторы для "склеивания" путей `append()` и `operator/=()` - соединяют пути через `/` и `concat()` и `operator+=()` - соединяют пути без добавления обратного слэша.
А для перевода в строку есть встроенный оператор `generic_string()`.
А вообще справка по классу помогает https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path